# Given a line parameterized by $(x,y)= (2t + 1,-3t +2)$, find a vector $(a,b)$ parallel to the line, such that $a+b=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the line parametrized by
>   \begin{align*} 
> x&= \phantom{-}2t + 1\\ 
> y& = -3t +2
> \end{align*}
>
> Find a vector $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ that's parallel to this line and satisfies $a+b = 3$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish the system of equations below from the slope and the given constraint,

$$\frac ba = - \frac 32$$

$$a+b=3$$

Then, solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the form
$$y=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{7}{2}$$